# Crafter CMS Rollback to default Thumbail

Tags: crafter-cms

I have a page with a thumbnail and I want to remove it and go back to the default image.

I have this values in the config.xml of the content-type

```
<previewable>true</previewable>
<noThumbnail>false</noThumbnail>
<image-thumbnail>image.jpg</image-thumbnail>
```

Then I change it to the one I have before

```
<previewable>true</previewable>
<noThumbnail>true</noThumbnail>
<image-thumbnail></image-thumbnail>
```

After this, all I got is a broken image link. I don't see the default preview image when I try to create a new content type.

I'm working on 2.5.x on alfresco as my content repository. I did the changes trough Alfresco Share

Am I missing something to pick the change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try:
admin console -> configuration -> click on “clear cache”.
See attached image.

[image: Clearing configuration cache]